# Express 4 server crashes right after loading statics files

Tags: node.js, express, production-environment, digital-ocean

I have working code on my local machine, but having issue running the same code on server (Digital Ocean). I have new / clean machine with Node `v0.10.36` no other services running, no other ports occupied / used.

After running `npm start` or `node bin/www` I see that server running, but after I visit the site, server crashes with following error:

```
root@video-dl:~/server# npm start

> server@0.0.0 start /root/server
> node ./bin/www

GET / 304 129.279 ms - -

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)

npm ERR! server@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/root/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /root/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
root@video-dl:~/server#
```

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) `ENOENT`means file or directory does not exist.

Mostly you can solve this issue by adding an absolute path into static folder definition.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

To check if the folder exists you can use real path:

```
console.log(fs.realpathSync(__dirname + '/public');
```

Comment: Might get the same error on certain operating systems when the process doesn't have read permission

Comment: I changed `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` => worked again on localhost but crashes on server. The console log is showing the current path and I am sure the files exists.

Comment: The code on server crashes before its gets to the realpath log - no mater where I put the log.

Comment: So now I tried it myself...  Looking for realpath with a not existing path lets my app crash... With exactly the same issue you posted initially.        var fs = require('fs');
console.log(fs.realpathSync('./fdgfd/dsfgsda/'));